# How to construct UML activity diagram reflecting real programmed source code as docs

Tags: uml, modeling, design, reverse-engineering, activity

Please, tell me the things I must use for modeling an (Enterprise Architect) activity diagram of

```
object1.method1() calls object2.method2()
```

I'm able to dragndrop a method of a class from model tree-view to my diagram, and it appears as new action there. But there is no hint about its belonging object. Also I don't get it which arrow type I must use to model that one calls the other.

My feeling is it's not very appropriate for constructing documentation of typical call scenarios of my application. You know I want to create UML docs for what we've programmed until now.

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: Sparx Enterprise Architect

Answer (score 5):

Activity diagrams don't use the concept of objects, as they usually don't show who does what, but only which actions/decisions are taken.
You could use partitions (also called swim lanes) to indicate who executes the actions, but if you have more than two or three objects interacting, this can become rather unreadable.

For describing the interactions between several objects, it will be better to use a [sequence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) or a [communication diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram) (sometimes referred to by its old name of collaboration diagram).

Comment: I don't get it why an activity diagram has such limitation. I dislike sequence diagrams a bit because I don't want to be limited to 1D and to show the time is not important to me there.

Comment: @falkb: you have to put a lot of effort in to let a sequence diagram show time information, but if you prefer, you can also use a communication diagram.

Comment: @falkb: The limitation on activity diagrams comes from the purpose for which they are meant to be used. They were meant to show procedural information, business processes and work flow and are somewhat comparable to flowcharts. None of this needs the concept of an object as it is used in OOP.

Comment: but one can also chain processes and flow to entities doing that and that is missing there. It's somehow limited to the special case "global scope", and that's why not sufficient to model OOP. You know activity comes always out of something.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion of communication diagram. I was able to create objects there by dragndrop from the classes in the model tree. But Sparx Enterprise Architect does not offer to connect them in the diagram with their class methods. That is only possible in sequence diagrams. So communication diagrams are useless for me to demonstrate source code communication (here: method calls) between objects, aren't they?

Comment: @falkb: In a communication diagram, you are supposed to be able to note down the method calls next to the lines connecting the objects (together with an arrow indicating the direction of the call and a sequence number). I'm not familiar with the tool you use, so I can't tell how to add that information to the diagram.

Comment: Which tool do you use? I tried several UML tools but they all lack such simple basic features needed to describe progammer's source code.

Comment: @falkb: I use a variety of tools, but most importantly, I use UML diagrams like a sketch pad, so I don't care about line-for-line correspondence with the code and I am thus not bothered if I have to re-type something because the tool can't reverse engineer it. That is mostly a difference in attitude towards UML.

Comment: hmm... this sounds like another indication that UML is good as general description language but still not well-suited as handy source code documentation tool, especially for fast and precise drag'n'drop from the reverse-engineered model tree.

Comment: @falkb: To me, it sounds more like tool support for your use case is lacking. UML does not describe how the diagrams should be create, only what they mean.

Comment: you're right, but EA is the best tool I've seen so far (followed by Visual Paradigm), so ...

Comment: You said `Activity diagrams don't use the concept of objects` but they do have a concept of object nodes which you can use to reflect object states in my opinion.

Comment: @cpx: Object nodes represent data or state-changes that are produced by a process. They can't be used to model who executes what.